# How should the nativescript-oauth2 library be implemented for Google OAuth2 sign-in for a NativeScript app running on iOS?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, nativescript, google-signin, nativescript-angular

I have implemented the nativescript-oauth2 library to perform third party sign-ins with Sign in with Google in a NativeScript Angular app. The sign-in process works correctly when running on an Android simulator and returns as expected to the app, but the sign-in process never completes when the app is running on an iOS simulator or on a connected iOS device.

A custom url scheme is registered for both the Android and iOS version of the app, respectively in the AndroidManifest.xml and Info.plist files. A Google client ID is defined for the iOS app in the Google developer console. The app is running on an Apple M1 MacBook, targeting version 16 of iOS, with version 14.3.1 of Xcode installed.

I obtained a Google client ID for an iOS app in the APIs and services section of the Google developer console, and declared this in the Info.plist file of the NativeScript app's iOS resource files as documented online for the library. On running the app on an iOS simulator, the login page loads the Google sign-in page correctly and that page accepts a successful authentication with a valid Google account. The page lands on the main Google page with the Google account signed-in in the browser after a period of approximately 10 seconds. I expected the device to successfully redirect to the NativeScript app with the login process callback function having been called.

Has anyone been developing apps with this library on iOS devices in recent years, and is there any known solution to this issue? Thanks for any help.